# :host selector for angular-material dialog

Tags: css, angular, dialog, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm using an [`dialog`](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) component from `angular-material` where I want to style the popup dialog.

I know there is some built-in support for styling through the generating component:

```
let dialogRef = dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, {
  height: '400px',
  width: '600px',
  panelClass: 'some-class'
});
```

But this causes the style definition to split up in the dialog component style and the generation definition. What I would like to do is adjust the dialog style itself for all dialogs of this type. A logical step would be to use `:host` on the component css:

```
:host {
    width: 600px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/4Kz14jMVRKyKzn0gLeAV?p=preview) to illustrate my point.

Is this in any way possible?

Comment: The Plunker throws an exception.

Comment: I know but it is not related to the issue at hand. The plunker template comes from the official documentation for the angular-material dialog and already had this error.

Comment: The module should be `  declarations: [DialogOverviewExample, DialogOverviewExampleDialog],
  bootstrap: [DialogOverviewExample],
  entryComponents: [DialogOverviewExampleDialog],`

Comment: The styles are applied (check the DOM in devtools), but it doesn't have any effect. Probably just overruled by other styles.

Answer (score 0):

[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/FVbEVdq5f2e6ahN7NsMx?p=preview)

I added `display: block`

```
:host { /* This is not working as expected */
  width: 800px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: block;
}
```

and changed this part in `PlunkerAppModule`

```
  declarations: [DialogOverviewExample, DialogOverviewExampleDialog],
  bootstrap: [DialogOverviewExample],
  entryComponents: [DialogOverviewExampleDialog],
  providers: []
})
```

Comment: I can't seem to load the linked plunker.(`xdomain.min.js:3 xdomain (https://plnkr.co): Timeout waiting on iframe socket`)

Comment: I still have to look at the example but I'm surprised that `display: block` would solve this issue. Originally this would have been `flex` and would not interfere with properties like `color` if i'd add them to `:host`.

Comment: Seems to be a temporary Plunker issue. The changes I made are in the answer directly. You should be able to reproduce locally in the meantime.

Comment: `block` is just an arbitrary change I made to prove that the styles are applied. I wouldn't say that this is the right way or the best way to do it.

Comment: I see! But this style is probably applied to a parent element and passed down. I think I went off on the wrong assumption that the `:host` would be the actual dialog but there's a full page wrapper and other components involved. I'll have to investigate using the `panelClass` as a (disappointing) alternative

Comment: The dialog is added outside your Angular application. This is because of styling limitations when the dialog is not a direct child of `<body>`. You can easily add styles to `index.html` to style the dialog-wrapping added by Angular.